# dynamic inheritance with type and super

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, dynamic, metaclass

I'm looking for a way to dynamically inherit a parent class with its attributes and methods, by using `type` for class creation and `super` for inheritance, like so:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
    def some_method(self,q):
        return (self.a + self.b)**q

def B_init(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

def another_method(self,):
    return 1

def class_B_factory(parent_class):
    return type(
        'B',
        (parent_class, some_other_parent_class),
        {'__init__':B_init,
         'another_method':another_method
        }
               )
```

And then be able to call...

```
model = class_B_factory(A)(a = 1, b = 5)
print(model.some_method(2)) # outputs to (1 + 5)**2 = 36
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't think I'll need a custom metaclass since I'm pretty sure you can't call the parent class' `__init__` method while also creating `self` in the process. I also tried overriding the default `__init__` method outside the scope of `class_B_factory` like so:

```
def class_B_factory(parent_class):
    return type(
        'B',
        (parent_class, some_other_parent_class),
        {'another_method':another_method
        }
               )

B = class_B_factory(A)

def B_init(self,**kwargs):
    super(B,self).__init__(**kwargs)

B.__init__ = B_init

model = B(a = 1, b = 5)
```

because I figured `type` doesn't need `__init__` right away, as it is only needed during instantiation. But then I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument` error, which seems like it didn't work, and its not clean anyway.

EDIT: I tried defining the methods outside the factory via the following but I am still unsuccessful. Not sure how to fix it. Python has trouble instantiating maybe?

```
class A:
    ...

def B_init(self, produced_class = None, **kwargs):
    super(produced_class,self).__init__(**kwargs)

def another_method(self, q, parent_class = None):
    if parent_class is not None:
        return 3 * parent_class.some_method(self,q) # I expect any parent_class passed to have a method called some_method
    return 1

def class_B_factory(parent_class, additional_methods):
    methods = {}
    for name, method in additional_methods.items():
        if "parent_class" in signature(method).parameters:
            method = partial(method, parent_class = parent_class) # freeze the parent_class argument, which is a cool feature
        methods[name] = method
    
    newcls = type(
            'B',
            (parent_class,),
            methods # would not contain B_init
                 )
    
    newcls.__init__ = partial(B_init, produced_class = newcls) # freeze the produced class that I am trying to fabricate into B_init here
    
    return newcls


model = class_B_factory(parent_class = A, additional_methods = {"another_method": another_method})

print(signature(model.__init__).parameters) # displays OrderedDict([('self', <Parameter "self">),...]) so it contains self!

some_instance_of_model = model(a = 1, b = 5) # throws TypeError: B_init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameterless form of `super()`  relies on it being physically placed inside a class body - the Python machinnery them will, under the hood, create a `__class__` cell variable referring that "physical" class (roughly equivalent to a non-local variable), and place it as the first parameter in the `super()`  call.

For methods not written inside `class` statements, one have to resort to explicitly placing the parameters to `super`, and these are the child class, and the instance (self).

The easier way to do that in your code is to define the methods inside your factory function, so they can share a non-local variable containing the newly created class in the super call:  ​

```
def class_B_factory(parent_class):

    def B_init(self,**kwargs):
        nonlocal newcls  # <- a bit redundant, but shows how it is used here
        ​super(newcls, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def another_method(self,):
        ​​return 1

   ​ newcls = type(
       ​'B',
       ​(parent_class, some_other_parent_class),
       ​{'__init__':B_init,
        ​'another_method':another_method
       ​}
    return newcls
```

If you have to define the methods outside of the factory function (which is likely), you have to pass the parent class into them in some form. The most straightforward would be to add a named-parameter  (say `__class__` or "parent_class"), and use `functools.partial` inside the factory to pass the parent_class to all methods in a lazy way:

```
from functools import partial
from inspect import signature

class A:
    ...


# the "parent_class" argument name is given a special treatement in the factory function:
def B_init(self, *, parent_class=None, **kwargs):
    nonlocal newcls  # <- a bit redundant, but shows how it is used here
    ​super([parent_class, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def another_method(self,):
    ​​return 1


def class_B_factory(parent_class, additional_methods, ...):
    methods = {}
    for name, method in additional_methods.items():
        if "parent_class" in signature(method).parameters:
            method = partial(method, parent_class=parent_class)
        # we populate another dict instead of replacing methods
        # so that we create a copy and don't modify the dict at the calling place.
        methods[name] = method
    

   ​ newcls = type(
       ​'B',
       ​(parent_class, some_other_parent_class),
       methods
    )
    return newcls

new_cls = class_B_factory(B, {"__init__": B_init, "another_method": another_method})
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't intend to write ``def B_init(self,**kwargs)`` twice? Anyway, this a great solution, and thanks for the help! I was wondering, what if I wanted to define the methods outside the factory function? Do you mind elaborating or sending a link to a related post on how to do that?

Comment: fixed both. I was time constrained when first answering.

Comment: Okay, so I imitated your second solution and I received a ``NameError: name 'B' is not defined`` and that makes sense considering you're passing in B as the ``parent_class`` and it hasn't been made yet via ``type``. In the context of the problem, the ``parent_class`` was supposed to be A and not B, since B is the subclass being created. However, I do understand that you are trying to pass the fabricated class object ``newcls`` as the first argument into ``super(..., self).__init__(**kwargs)`` under ``B_init``, right? I tried that (see edit) and I am still getting an error: ...

Comment: ... ``TypeError: B_init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'``

Comment: Your first solution was helpful, so I will approve it.